# Subversion : assign new password to user

Tags: svn

How can I reset the password (respectively assign a new one) for a user who has forgotten his password? Passwords are not stored in plain text in his home.

The subversion server runs on Windows 7, as do the clients.

svn.exe says that it is version 1.8.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

On the server, there is a directory called conf inside the repository, and inside it has a file called passwd. I found that passwords are stored there in plain text.

In short: There doesn't seem to be a special tool for this task; it's just editing a file.